# rpsec No examples found

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Hello i have read the other questions similar to this and they didn't help.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

When i run rspec spec i receive this error

```
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00027 seconds (files took 0.07589 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Here is the tree structure

[image]
book.spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Book do

    before :each do
      @book = Book.new "Title", "Author", :category
    end

    describe "#new" do
        it "returns a new book object"
            @book.should be_an_instance_of Book
        end
    end

end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require_relative '../library'
require_relative '../book'

require 'yaml'
```

I have 
ruby 2.2.1p85
Rails 4.2.3

Comment: In which directory did you run `rspec spec`?

Comment: I had this problem because I was in the wrong directory.  I was in spec.  When I moved up to root dir, it worked fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file name is wrong. You have book.spec.rb and it should be book_spec.rb.

Also:

- You don't have to require any spec file in your spec_helper. When you run `$ rspec` it will read all '*_spec' files on your spec/ folder.
- You should put that model test inside `spec/models` folder.

You can read more about the standard structure of a Rails test suite here:
http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/directory-structure

And this is a great place to learn about good practices about Rspec.
http://betterspecs.org/